# mockk: Specify different behaviors for the same method before vs after calling another method?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mocking, mockk

Say I want to test `myService` by calling `myService.createStuff` first, then call `myService.getStuff`, then `myService.deleteStuff` to delete the `Stuff` I just created, and finally call `myService.getStuff` again.

Specifying the behavior for `deleteStuff` and `createStuff` seems straight-forward:

```
coEvery { myService.createStuff(any()) } returns Stuff
coEvery { myService.deleteStuff(any()) } returns Nothing? 
// deleteStuff returns null upon success
```

But how can I specify the behavior for `getStuff()`? The part that I don't know how to get around is: `getStuff` should behave differently before vs after `deleteStuff()` is called. How can I do this? Thanks.

I have tried looking into [argument matching](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-expected-behavior-and-behavior-verification-3862dd0e0f03), but in the [matchers list](https://mockk.io/#matchers), I have not found a suitable one for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
coEvery { myService.getStuff() } returnsMany listOf(firstResult, secondResult)
```

This will return `firstResult` on the first call and `secondResult` on the second call